# Replacing the Prod Repo after rewriting git history?

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history

I to purged my repo's history of large files using used [The BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#usage) and following the usage steps described.  So I now have a clean bare repo ready to be pushed back to GitHub.

The production directory is a clone of that repo.

Since the HEAD is protected, does that mean that in principle, after doing the push to GitHub,  I'll be able to pull into the existing prod clone and get the "Already up-to-date." message, and I can then if necessary, I could also push from that prod repo back to GitHub cleanly?

Or will I run into trouble if I make hot production mods to push up to the repo? (It's a very ancient project with lots of bad practices cooked in.  I've got developers without git skill working in prod directly.)

Comment: If you've rewritten history, then you'll need to do a force push.  But I don't really understand what you mean by "a pull into this prod directory will do nothing and can I straight from there push back?".  Why would you need to push back from your production checkout?  (And why does that have anything to do with your question?)

Comment: Clarified the question.  I believe that the bare repo that I push back to GitHub replaces all refs (thus a force push?).  But then I've got this existing original directory/repo clone in production that I'll be pushing and pulling to and from.  Using The BFG, I rewrote the history in an entirely different location unrelated to original prod repo.  So I want to be sure that I won't see everything "changed but not updated".

Comment: Well, you won't be able to update your prod checkout, as it's a fundamentally different history now.  You'll need to create a brand new checkout.

Comment: It appears that rebasing might resolve the issue?  https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, to understand your setup, there are 3 copies of your repository:

1. Your **local** copy, cleaned with the BFG
2. The copy on **GitHub**
3. The **production** copy, which I guess is sitting on a live server somewhere

You're ready to push your cleaned **local** history to **GitHub**, but you're wondering what the minimum action is you need to take against **production**. I'm assuming that **local**, **GitHub** and **production** were all in sync before you started.

The BFG [does protect the 'contents'](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#protected-commits) (specifically the file-tree) of your HEAD commit, but that doesn't mean the *history* of that commit. Although it guarantees the *files* in that commit won't have changed, the BFG **has** to change history in order to do it's job. Because Git is careful to treat history as (normally) unchangeable, you can't just `git pull` those changes down normally into your **production** copy- the differing history will be noticed by Git, and then rejected. All the rubbish you were trying to get rid of will also be retained, and there's a risk you would push it back to GitHub if you're not careful.

Instead fetch the changes, telling Git to explicitly force every local branch history to the new, cleaned, version:

```
$ git fetch origin *:* -f --update-head-ok
```

*(the `--update-head-ok` flag is to avoid `Refusing to fetch into current branch` errors)*

After that, you should be fine to fetch any new history, and even push hot production mods back to GitHub, if that's required.

Comment: Getting problems: * Ignoring funny ref 'HEAD' locally, Refusing to fetch into current branch refs/heads/master of non-bare repository.  Is this a git version issue?  git version 1.7.1

Comment: Tried with 2.2, no dice.  Did a git fetch origin -f (no *:*), that worked, but trying a push back resulted in the old cruft still in the repo.

Comment: @ijames updated answer to add the `--update-head-ok` flag - thanks for pointing out the problem!